# Is character count with spaces possible in LaTex?

Tags: characters, thesis, count

Hi I've really tried to google around on this one, but nothing has worked for me. Anyone who knows, if it is possible to count characteristics with space?

Thank you in advance.

Best,
Maria

Comment: Please provide some additional information to help make your question more precise: Are you trying to count the source or the output? How do you count math? What are the non-working solutions you found?

Comment: not a job for latex, use pdf tools to count the text in the pdf

Comment: Some editors will also provide this information for the source. But counts for the source are basically approximations. (Counts for the PDF may or may not be much better.)

Comment: Hi everyone - thank you all for the responses. I'll try the PDF solution, thank you very much and have a great day.